# How to implement KeyListener in my drum set program?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm trying to make a drum set that will play based off of key inputs, but the key inputs are not reaching the array list.

I've tried putting the array lists in different programs, I've tried strings and characters.

```
package instruments;
```

### '''java'''

Drumset

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Drumset extends Canvas  implements Runnable{

static KeyEvent keyevent;
static MyKeyListener keys = new MyKeyListener();
static ArrayList<String> instrument = new ArrayList<String>();//collects key inputs
public static final int width = 800, height = width;
public Thread thread;
public boolean running = false;


public Drumset(){
    this.addKeyListener(keys);
    new Window(width,height,"Drumset", this);

}


public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void findInstrument(){

}


public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountofticks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountofticks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta>= 1){
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
    findInstrument();
    if(running){
        render();
        frames ++;
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
        timer += 1000;
        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
        frames = 0;
    }
    }
    stop();

}

public void tick(){

}

public void render(){
    BufferStrategy buffer = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (buffer == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics pen = buffer.getDrawGraphics();

    pen.setColor(Color.black);
    pen.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

    buffer.show();

}
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Drumset();

}
```

}

---

MyKeyListener

```
package instruments;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {


private ArrayList<Character> keyInstruments = new ArrayList<Character>();

public MyKeyListener() {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println(key);
//          bass
            if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_B)){
                keyInstruments.add('b');
            }
//          hi-hat
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_H)){
                keyInstruments.add('h');
            }
//          crash cymbal
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_C)){
                keyInstruments.add('c');
            }
//          floor tom
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_F)){
                keyInstruments.add('f');
            }
//          high tom
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_T)){
                keyInstruments.add('t');
            }
//          low tom
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_L)){
                keyInstruments.add('l');
            }
//          ride cymbal
            else if (key == (KeyEvent.VK_R)){
                keyInstruments.add('r');
            }
        }


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    for(int c = 0; c < keyInstruments.size(); c++) {
        if(keyInstruments.get(c) == e.getKeyChar()) {
            keyInstruments.remove(c);
            return;
        }
    }
}
public int getSize(){
    return keyInstruments.size();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public ArrayList<Character> getKey() {
    return keyInstruments;
}
```

}

I expect the output to be whatever keys are pressed that are also included in the KeyPressed method.

Comment: please post all code here with your question, not in a link. Please understand that this is not a help site, but rather a question and answer site, meaning both the questions and the answers have to help future visitors, and for this reason (and others) all relevant material should be immediately available within the question itself. Please go through the [help] the [ask] and the [mcve] sites for more on this

Comment: Your `Drumset` class extends `java.awt.Canvas`. `Canvas` is known as a _heavyweight_ component. You add a `Drumset` to a `JFrame`. `JFrame` is a _lightweight_ component. It is generally accepted that you should not mix heavyweight and lightweight components. See the article entitled [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). You can use a `JPanel` instead of a `Canvas`.

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Method `keyPressed()` in class `MyKeyListener` is called and that class's member variable `keyInstruments` is updated. And an element is removed from `keyInstruments` in method `keyReleased()`.

Comment: @Abra where does his program show the key presses? The KeyListener fills an ArrayList, but does nothing with this list, does not display it, store it, nothing. But regardless, the OP needs to post his code in his question for it to be answered.

Comment: @Abra: Goodlopi's suggestions would make sense if the code did something with the key MyKeyListener field, but it doesn't. It's an object that's been created and ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I had to do to fix it was add the keylistener in my window class instead of my Drumset class.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
frame.addKeyListener(listen);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your drumset class you initialize a static MyKeyListener() called keys, but you don't seem to use it later on in the code.

I would suggest replacing

```
public Drumset(){
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        new Window(width,height,"Drumset", this);

    }
```

With

```
public Drumset(){
        this.addKeyListener(keys);
        new Window(width,height,"Drumset", this);

    }
```

This might not be the correct answer but its the best i can do to help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with his problem

Comment: The keylistener class he has created is not added to the game window at all in his code from what i can see, meaning the key listener can't be used, regardless of key presses.

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken. In the constructor of class `Drumset`, there is this line: `this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());` which means a key listener is added. The class member variable `keys` is not used in class `Drumset` or anywhere in the project.